# Lost power during my upgrade , how do i recover?

Tags: upgrade, partial-upgrade

I was upgrading my 12.04 to 14.04. During the install step, I accidentally lost power to my laptop(sockets didn't work) and got shutdown.when i tried to start my ubuntu,till login password it is coming afterwards it is a plain display, nothing is coming and files are not loading.

How i can recover my ubuntu,is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Reboot in recovery mode (choose recovery from Grub menu), log in and issue:

```
dpkg-reconfigure -a
```